# Nav menu dropdown is not working Angular4 Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

In my Angular4 app I created a standard nav bar. When the screen size decreases the nav menu dropdown appears. When clicking on the menu dropdown, the (collapsed) links are not shown.

Question: how can I get the menu dropdown working for Angular 4 + Bootstrap 3?

I created a standard  component. This is the template file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a routerLink="/search" class="navbar-brand">Brand-name</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a routerLink="/search">Search</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/edit">Edit</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a routerLink="/signup">Signup</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Of course I read similar questions and articles, but none helped me any further. Most are about Boostrap only, not the combination with Angular 4.

Comment: Bootstrap comes with some jquery libraries for collapsing stuff. Did you import them? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start

Comment: Yes, I inserted jquery.3.2..0.js and bootstrap.js to index.html. Is that the right place? I did not place the header-html as part of the index.html because the routerlinks wouldn't work. Should I import them via the scripts tag of angular-cli?  Please show what I should include where. Workig with a seperate <header> seems to be a good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All answers so far show how to open the dropdown menu. The answers don't show how to collapse that dropdown menu again after selecting on a menu item.

Thanks to Thomas Rundle the basic parts can be found in the [following solution](https://medium.com/@ct7/the-simple-way-to-make-a-mobile-angular-2-bootstrap-navbar-without-jquery-d6b3f67b037b).  I added some code. The header.component.ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  isIn : boolean = false;   // store state
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  toggleState() { // click handler
    let bool = this.isIn;
    this.isIn = bool === false ? true : false;
  }
}
```

The template header.component.html is:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="toggleState()">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button> <!-- #1 -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/page1">Project Manager</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse in" [ngClass]="{ 'in': isIn }">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a role="tab" (click)="toggleState()" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/page1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a role="tab" (click)="toggleState()" data-toggle="tab" routerLink="/page2">Page 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- #2 -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap Drop down adds a class open to the `<ul>` element for the drop down to appear and close , you can make use of Angular Directives to add the Same behaviour to the Component.

**App Drop Down Directive**

```
  import {Directive, HostListener, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

  @Directive({
    selector: '[appDropdown]'
  })
  export class DropdownDirective {

    private isOpen:boolean = false;

    @HostBinding('class.open') get opened(){
      return this.isOpen;
    }
    constructor() { }

    @HostListener('click')open(){
      this.isOpen = true;
    }

    @HostListener('mouseleave')close(){
      this.isOpen = false;
    }
```

Stick it to your ul `<ul class="nav navbar-nav" appDropdown>`

A working [**Example**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts)
[**Code**](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you. When clicking on the hamburger the menu opens. OK. 
ISSUE - on clicking on a menu item, how to close it again?

Comment: @tjm1706 my code has a eveny on mouse leave. You need to add a different event for that. That itself is a new question as you need to check where the click came from

Comment: Sighn - Clicking on the menu item is the real issue. I tried many different approaches. Please HELP. This is of course only applicable on small screens when there is a dropdown menu due to the size of the screen.

Comment: @tjm1706 you need to another directive for the same i guess, if you want to acheive it in angular way

Comment: How? Can you show me a solution? I guess this is a very general question for angular developers.

Comment: @tjm1706 if you look at the example link i provided, there when you click on the menu the drop down opens and you can click on any link, but when you hover out i:e the normal user X then if disappears i guess this is proper dnt you think

Comment: Clicking any menu item should remove the dropdown menu items and have the normal hamburger menu shown. On clicking a menu item I can attach a router link. I can also attach a (click) to call a method. How can I access the Dropdown directive to call the close() method? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/oSKnNWXNafbMjCiPwqrv?p=preview

since you have target="#navbar", you have to set the id of the target to navbar for it to work.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a routerLink="/search" class="navbar-brand">Brand-name</a>
            </div>

            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a routerLink="/search">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a routerLink="/edit">Edit</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a routerLink="/signup">Signup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try the responsiveness, the dropdown does not disappear on medium to larger screens. You can see that behaviour  without your code. Because it is a failry common code, can you help a bit further?